# Subtable in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I need to display in a report viewer (rdlc file) a list of customer (One customer per page), and orders related to that customer (On same page of customer info) and comments. How do I insert the tablix so that there is a page break for each customer?

This is how it should look:

[image]

And this is how i'm looking to add data on report:

```
List<Customer> customers = db.Customers;

LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Customers", customers))

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: Maybe I did not express properly. I dont know how to display each customer's orders and comments on list items. How do I need to group? How do i set DataSet to Sub Table (For orders and comments)

Comment: In report designer, right click this item and select " Insert a page break before this list" should works.

Comment: Add a row group on Customer to the Tablix, set the row group to page break after group change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use subreport:

1. One big report for Title (Name and phone), subreports positions and page break
2. One subreport for Orders (CustomersOrders.rdlc): Adding a subreport parameter (CustomerId)
3. One subreport for Comments (CustomersComments.rdlc): Adding a subreport parameter (CustomerId)
4. A static property on report renderer window that contains a list of customers

On report renderer window add an SubreportProcessing handler:

```
LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += Customers_SubreportProcessing;

private void Customers_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    ReportParameterInfo customerId = e.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "CustomerId");
    if (customerId== null)
        return;

    Customer customer = _customersList
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == customerId.Values.FirstOrDefault());

    if (e.ReportPath == "CustomersOrders") // Name for subreport CustomersOrders.rdlc
    {
        e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Orders", customer.Orders));
    }
    else if (e.ReportPath == "CustomersComments") // Name for subreport CustomersComments.rdlc
    {
        e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Comments", customer.Comments));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following MSDN page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207058.aspx
indicates that if you want to add a page break to a row group in a table, matrix, or list then follow these steps:

1. In the Grouping pane, right-click a row group, and then click *Group Properties*.
2. On the Page Breaks tab, select *Between each instance of a group* to add a page break between each instance of a group in the table.
3. Optionally, select *Also at the start of a group* or *Also at the end of a group* to specify that a page break be added when a group starts or ends in the table.